# WPF Window Activate Not Capturing Focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a legacy C++ application and a WPF application that communicate via sockets. The legacy application launches a WPF window by sending data over the socket that the WPF application handles. The application creates a Window and calls the Activate method on it. Topmost is set to true on the window and back to false like so to bring the window to the front.

`window.Topmost = true;
window.Activate();
window.Topmost = false`;

The problem is that sometimes focus remains in the parent C++ window although the WPF window is activated and on top. When Activate() returns true, focus is in the WPF window. When Activate() returns false, focus is in the C++ window. Does anyone have any ideas on how to move focus to the WPF window every time?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: perhaps the C++ window want to regain focus due to a mouse event eg. click on a button which triggers the concerned action.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the legacy C++ window isn't requesting focus to my knowledge. This does happen via a double click event in the C++ window that the WPF application is launched. However, no further processing is done with the C++ window afterwards.

Comment: Did you try using "window.Focus()"?

Answer (score 0):

Set Focus to any control in the WPF window. This should make the window the focused window.